# What is this format code (\r\a) I get when using office interop in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am writing some code to iterate through the tables of a Word document (number of tables in the 100s but I don't think this matters) and populate their fields with data from tables found in another word document using c# in Visual Studio.

Basically copying data from some tables in document B to the tables in document A. I need to make sure several cells from document B and document A match before I migrate the data, but this is proving difficult because the data has formatting that ends up causing errors because the two fields aren't equal though they have the same visible text.

To pull the text from the individual cells in the table I was using

```
table.Cell(row,col).Range.Text;
```

But this has returned a value such as "This Cell's value\r\a"
so I've had to modify remove

```
table.Cell(row,col).Range.Replace("\r\a","").Text;
```

This works but I am wondering if there is another less cumbersome way to achieve the result or what the *\r\a* actually mean. Looking through Google and StackOverflow, I wasn't able to find out anything that answered my questions. Thanks.

Comment: See: [String Escape Sequences (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences).

Comment: Thanks, I believed this to be something from Word and never thought to check if it was in c#. I appreciate the reference!

Comment: This sequence is atypical, usually one would use `"\r\n"` for Carriage Return + Line Feed for line breaks in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character combination ANSI 13 + ANSI 7 define table structure (end-of-cell / end-of-row) and as such need to be trimmed from text strings obtained from reading a table cell's content. I use a function such as the following. Using `Replace` is not advisable as a table cell could contain additional ANSI 13 (paragraph marks, what you think of as "new lines", but in Word these are more than that - think of html p vs br, which is ANSI 11 in Word, a new line).

```
//cut off ANSI 13 + ANSI 7 from the end of the string coming from a 
//Word table cell
private string TrimCellText2(s As String)
{
    int len = s.Length;
    while (len > 0 && s.Substring(len - 1) == (char)13 || s.Substring(len - 1) == (char)7);
    {
        s = s.Substring(0, Math.Min(len-1, len));   
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also solves the issue and I understand what you mean about the issues that could arise from the Replace. I appreciate it! My research is failing me in finding any sort of compiled list of these character combinations and their functionality in Word. Do you know if one exists readily available on the internet?